# are BCrypt and SCrypt a Key Derivation Functions?

Tags: bcrypt, pbkdf2, scrypt

am sorry for this question, but i always find them compared to PBKDF2, so are BCrypt and SCrypt KDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that i've found the answer:

- Short answer YES.
- Long answer: look here [PDF](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf)

by the way, it seems that BCrypt have a limitation of 55 characters !!!